# Cocos2d-x app in landscape shows some iOS UI elements in portrait (sideways)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit, cocos2d-x

I am building a landscape `cocos2d-x` game and while working on the `iOS` version I am realizing that a a progress hud (`SVProgressHUD`) shows on screen sideways as if it thinks the app is portrait.

In XCode I have Device Orientation set to Landscape right, then in my `RootViewController` I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation );
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

My game is correctly in landscape, but not the progress HUD. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a method: - `(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: Do you have the entries in your plist file?